# Why aren’t my flags handled?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, moderators, profile-page, flagging

The last handled flag on my profile is from 21 February. None of the newer flags have been handled yet. Where are all the moderators?

Comment: See: [What happens when you reach zero flag weight?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82445/what-happens-when-you-reach-zero-flag-weight)

Answer (score 11):

Without going into the specific numbers:

- 39% of your standard flags have been declined or disputed.
- 34% of your spam flags were declined.

This is simply too high. It's normal to have a couple of declined flags, but not a third of your total.

You were already contacted about your flagging behavior in September 2012. We encouraged you to take a look at your flagging record to try and improve, which obviously didn't happen.

Comment: There's not much you can do, sorry. You *have* been warned. This is not a manually enforced ban, so we can't undo it.

Comment: Well yes, you did. You got a moderator message about this. Checking again, it seems you haven't read it though…? Other than that, there's no explicit message, yeah. This is probably intentional.

Comment: Could good spam and offensive flags gain back flag weight in that case? (since they don't require anyone to look at it in a queue in order to be considered "helpful")

Comment: @cpast The flags simply won't be handled anymore. Moderators cannot act on them even if they wanted.

Comment: But what if other users independently flag the same post as spam? In that case, I was under the impression that all the spam flags were auto-marked "helpful". Unless it doesn't even store a weight 0 user's flag?

Comment: @cpast Even then, the flag will not be dismissed with the others. As I said, the flags can't be acted on anymore.

Answer (score 6):

The short answer is too many of your flags have been declined, hence your flags don't show up on our queue

Comment: Just to be clear: 1) Flag weight is no longer displayed but used only internally for ordering the queue, right? 2) Are disputed flags clubbed with declined ones for the purposes of calculation? (IMO that really shouldn't be the case.) 3) What about declined/disputed flags that have been discussed and for which the previously rejected actions have been carried out - is there no mechanism for switching those flags to helpful? 4) What percentage of bad flags indicates a danger area where further flags from a user no longer show up on a mod's queue?

Comment: @Karan lets suffice it to say that while your concerns may be valid, in this particular matter the number of declined flags are so high that there's no doubt the ban is working as intended. For any specific concerns I'd recommend starting a new Meta questions, possibly on MSO

Comment: To be perfectly clear, my comment was in *no* way related to the issue at hand or OP above. Just seeing this discussion made me think of some related queries about flagging, so I thought I'd get some quick answers from you. I've been checking out MSO and if not all my queries are answered I'll post a new question. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Check if you have an unusual amount of declined flags. If your flag weight hits zero because of that, none of your flags are shown to moderators anymore. If you have at least 10 declined flags and more declined flags than helpful flags the odds are high that your flags are not shown to the mods anymore.